# How do I report error messages from PayPal iOS SDK to users?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

The app I am administering has used the PayPal SDK for iOS, and this works fine for the most part, except that if a user tries to login and gets an error, the error is not reported to the user.

For example, if I use incorrect login credentials, I'll get this error message:

```
2018-07-12 10:21:28.316449-0400 AppName[52601:6030601] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: invalid_user - Incorrect username/password. Please try again. (401) | PayPal Debug-ID: a1f66774362f, a1f66774362f [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.17.0] | Details: (
```

Ultimately, when I try to login with these credentials, it gets as far as this function, and then seems to go no further.

```
func segueToConfigurePaypal(sender: UIButton?) {
    print("DEBUG Segue to configure paypal")

    let scopeValues: Set = [kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress]

    let config = PayPalConfiguration()
    config.merchantName = "example"
    config.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/privacy")
    config.merchantUserAgreementURL = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/terms")

    let vc = PayPalProfileSharingViewController.init(scopeValues: scopeValues, configuration: config, delegate: self)

    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

All of which connects to the SDK.

I am wondering if there's a way to make an event listener that will let me know if there's been a problem with the user logging in. This way a user can have some idea about why they're having trouble rather than thinking it is an issue with the app.

Basically I want an alert on user login issues, that reports the issue to the user.

Comment: The PayPal iOS SDK is now deprecated. Use: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios

Comment: That's not a solution to this problem. The API is already in use, has been for over a year and is the basis of the current PayPal integration for the app. While upgrading the API would be great, I need to get my client to sign-off on that, and that's unlikely to happen. This is not a new project, I'm just trying to get an error value from an existing project. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander are you able to check the condition weather payment is processable or not?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander this error is happening inside the presented Paypal VC, and that's why you are not able to access it? What happens within that view controller when incorrect login occurs, does it pop itself off the navigation stack? You could show an alert when that occurs?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Have you tried using PayPalProfileSharingDelegate?